# React hook forms: select tag doesn't give an error after submit even though the option is disabled and has undefined as its value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
          <form
            className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          >
                  <select
                    name="Test"
                    defaultValue={item && item.RightToAct}
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    className="form-inputs"
                  >
                    <option disabled selected value={undefined}>
                      Choose an option
                    </option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                  </select>
                  {errors.Test &&
                    errors.Test.type === "required" && (
                      <p style={{ color: "red " }}>
                        Choosing an option is required.
                      </p>
                    )}
           </form>
```

As you can see I just want to a simple text to show up when the chosen option is the disabled one. Even though it is disabled it still accepts that option, I even gave it a value of undefined to see if that would trigger the error but it still accepts the option as right.

I am using React-hook-forms for this and the live demo at the bottom of the page has a good demo with a default value that doesn't pass the errors : https://react-hook-form.com/

Reproduction of my question: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-shirley-yg3s4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello! Can you make simple minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/? Would be easier to spot the error that way! Thank you.

Comment: @Danila Added the codesandbox.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using some older version of `react-hook-form` (v6). Are you tied to it? If not, it's better to use latest version, it has better api and fewer bugs!

I've updated your example with latest version and it works fine now, [check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70699323-i7s7g?file=/src/App.js)

One note: `select` component should be controlled via `value` prop (handled automatically by `react-hook-form` in our example), not via `selected` prop on the `option` (that's React limitation, not `react-hook-form`). And it's better to use empty string value for empty option, not `undefined`.

Comment: This is a project I inherited, the person before me used this version of react-hook-form so I used the same one. I think Ill just use 2 versions and use your fix. Thank you!